# How do I print the current NixOS' nix.package version?

Tags: nixos

A NixOS configuration is built using the `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` file. This configuration has a `nix.package` property.

In an NixOS instance, I want to print the version/hash (i.e., unique identifier) of the `nix.package` object that has been used in building the current instance. Ideally, this should be stored inside a lockfile, but I don't believe the current version of `nixos-rebuild` uses those.

Should this not be possible, can I explicitly store this hash somewhere during the build process by modifying my `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`?

Comment: For what purpose would you like to use a lockfile?
We generally lock sources before evaluation (pinning), or we can work with the system "top-level" store path for binary deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access this attribute via NixOS' `config` parameter and use it in your configuration, or as part of a package.

For example, this module causes the version and the store path to be written to files in `/etc` upon activation.

```hs
{ config, lib, ... }:
{
  config = {
    environment.etc."x-nix-version".text =
      config.nix.package.version;
    environment.etc."x-nix-path".text =
      "${config.nix.package}";
  };
}
```

Alternatively, you can extract it from a potentially not yet built configuration using the `nixos-option` command or `nix repl '<nixpkgs/nixos>'`.